# Jquery: show IMG on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preview of how it should be: https://www.youtube.com/embed/8qKRf0cg3Co

As in the video, I have to click on the `img` to get a large view of the `img` under it.

So far this is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>JQUERY</title>
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
<center>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="nav">
    <div id="overbalk"></div>
    <img src="images/foto_01.png" align="top" class="foto" />
    <img src="images/foto_02.png" align="top" class="foto" />
    <img src="images/foto_03.png" align="top" class="foto" />
    <img src="images/foto_04.png" align="top" class="foto" />
</div>

<div id="content">
    <img src="images/foto_01.png" align="top" class="slide_foto" />
</div>

</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: black;
}
#nav {
width: 600px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
#overbalk {
width: 600px;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
}
.foto {
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
margin-top:  -20px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.foto:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
z-index: -2;
width: 100%;
}
.slide_foto {
margin-left:-3200px;
}
</style>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.foto').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '+=50'}, 200);
    });
    $('.foto').mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '-=50'}, 200);
    });
    $('.foto').click(function () {
        $(this).next('#content').show();
    });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$('.foto').on('click', function () {
    $('#content').html(nieuwe_foto).show();
    var nieuwe_foto = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.slide_foto').attr('src', nieuwe_foto);
}
```

None of this worked, and got a little bit stuck, the images aren't showing below the small images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes:

1. Remove this style class from `<style>`

   ```
   .slide_foto {
       margin-left:-3200px;
   }
   ```
2. Make this change in your onclick handler

   ```
   $('.foto').on('click', function () {
       var nieuwe_foto = $(this).prop('src');
       $('.slide_foto').prop('src', nieuwe_foto);
   });
   ```

I have made a working fiddle with sample images  https://jsfiddle.net/sachin_puthran/c2qgjpj1/

The following doesn't do anything since `nieuwe_foto` is undefined until the next line and `div#content` is already visible `.show()` doesn't do anything either.

```
$('#content').html(nieuwe_foto).show();
```

Comment: Thank you. it helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

The `.show()` isn't what you're looking for. It will essentially "unhide" an element. So if an element has a `display: none` style then `.show()` will restore the initial display style. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

You're closer with your second attempt though. All you want to do in the `$('.foto').click` function is set the src of the `.slide_foto` element to what is currently in the src of the `this` object.